# SharePoint list field populated from REST query response

Tags: sharepoint

I'm in search of steps to accomplish the following.  I have a monitoring API query that returns response body containing a value between 0 to 100.  I want to create a SharePoint list field that will store the value that API call.

For instance, imagine I have a SharePoint list of 3 rows.

Row 1 calls the API and returns the value 90
Row 2 calls the API and returns the value 60
Row 2 calls the API and returns the value 40

I would like a column in the list to surface these values.

Ideally, what I will do with these values is this.  If the value is 90, I will show a GREEN status image in a status column of type image.  If the value is 60, I will show a YELLOW status image in a status column of type image.  If the value is 40, I will show a RED status image in a status column of type image.

What I'm struggling to find through basic Google and Bing searches are any code that illustrates how and where an API query can be executed for every row in a SharePoint list and populate a column, say text OR numeric column

................................

BY THE WAY, I haven't written my API function yet but my intent is to simply return a number between 0 to 100 in the response body.  But I'd be curious to know how the guidance would change if the response body is fixed in JSON format.  Can someone provide additional tips to parse the JSON body to retract the 90, 60 and 40 values?

Thanks

Bingfoot

Comment: do you want to call the api when an item on the list is created or just get all data from list, and for each element call your api and update an item?

Comment: That's correct Tinamou.  I want a workflow that iterates through all the rows in a list, calls an API and puts the value returned from the API in a column, say column A.  But column B must display an image, dependent on the value of column A.  For instance, if column A is 90, column B should display a GREEN image icon.  But if column A is 40, then column B should display a RED image icon.